# Angular JS ng-options don't take value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I'm trying to do something I've done several times in the current project, but somehow it won't work now.

I have an array with objects in it:

```
$scope.teacherList = [
    {"id":1,"firstName":"Dave","lastName":"Squarepants"},   
    {"id":2,"firstName":"Patrick","lastName":"Star"}
]
```

Now I make a select box with ng-options:

```
<select name="teacher" ng-model="crudTeacher.teacher.id" 
                       ng-options="teacher.id as teacher.firstName + ' ' + 
                                   teacher.lastName for teacher in teacherList" required>
</select>
```

But when I look at the values, ist just 0 and 1, even if the id's are 1 and 2.

Angular somehow doesn't take the teacher.id as ... part correctly.

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my sample , it does display the correct values :

http://jsbin.com/quhigumu/2/edit

[image]

[image]

Comment: But look at the value attributes:
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="0">Dave Squarepants</option>
<option value="1">Patrick Star</option>

Comment: @DavidFariña Oh do you mean by inspecting the element ? If so , don't. NG takes care for the values in other place. ( so you dont see it in the dom).